# How to get rid of platform dependency for my RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have the following RelativeLayout (landscape mode) in my application:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivLeft" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivRight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivLeft"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivClose"
        android:onClick="onClose" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivSwitch"
        android:onClick="onSwitch" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivAnaglyph"
        android:onClick="onAnaglyph" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivWiggle"
        android:onClick="onWiggle" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivSave"
        android:onClick="onSave" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It renders correctly (at least it renders the same) on different mobile platforms like modern HTC, LG, One Plus etc. The result should be that the two images (of the same size) split the landscape screen into two equal halves. The smaller symbols are on the left hand side below each other (covering the left image).

But the latest Sony XPeria (Z3 and M4 Aqua) beg to differ. The small symbols are positioned correctly, but the first big image takes more than half of the screen (it moves significantly to the right) so the second image has not enough space left to maintain its full size. I already tried to temporarily remove the small symbols, with no difference at all!

Maybe I need a new approach: How can I split the landscape layout into two equal halves, independent of the resulting platform? I'm not forced to use RelativeLayout ... what would help me here?

Comment: Use a LinearLayout with **weights**. By the way, `fill_parent` is **deprecated**. Use `match_parent`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Frank N. Stein I was able to solve the issue with two RelativeLayouts nested inside a LinearLayout using weights like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ivLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivClose"
            android:onClick="onClose" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivSwitch"
            android:onClick="onSwitch" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivAnaglyph"
            android:onClick="onAnaglyph" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivWiggle"
            android:onClick="onWiggle" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivSave"
            android:onClick="onSave" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ivRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```